# Comment `Reply` link doesn't work if comments are loaded from ajax

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, comment-form, comments

I am writing a plugin that displays custom home page that is in fact **only one post with comments**. The first time home page is displayed by the initial call by php. Then user can click a menu button to get another post. This is handled by ajax. So the whole page does not reload.

Getting and displaying other posts via ajax works fine till I 'refresh' the page via ajax. Then the comment `reply` link doesn't work any more.

I implemented [AJAXified commenting system][1] but I guess it has nothing to do with reply link.

Reply link before ajax is used looks like

```
<a onclick="return addComment.moveForm(&quot;div-comment-11&quot;, &quot;11&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;8&quot;)" 
href="/?replytocom=11#respond" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a>
```

When the same post is loaded via ajax the reply button looks like

```
<a onclick="return addComment.moveForm(&quot;div-comment-11&quot;, &quot;11&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;8&quot;)" 
href="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?replytocom=11#respond" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a>
```

The difference is in the `href` attribute. The second (ajax) one got `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` part that does not supposed to be there.

I use one php function to generate html for both the fist time post is being displayed and for ajax call too.

Part of the function looks like

```
   function my_get_comments($post_id, $number_of_comments){
    //Gather comments for a specific post 
    $comments =     get_comments(array(
        'number' => $number_of_comments,
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
    ));

    ob_start(); //workaround how to capture the output from comments_number() function
        comments_number( 'no comments', 'one comment', '% comments' );
    $capture_comments_number = ob_get_clean();

    $return_string ='<div id="comments_container">'
                    . '<style type="text/css">.hidden{display:none;}</style>'
                    . '<div id="comments_number">'
                        . $capture_comments_number
                        . '<a class="comment_switch"> Show / Hide Comments</a>'
                    . '</div>'
                    . '<div class="comments">'
                    . '<ol class="commentlist">';


    //Display / format the list of comments

    ob_start(); //workaround how to capture the output from wp_list_comments() function
        wp_list_comments(array(
            'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
        ), $comments);
    $capture_wp_list_comments = ob_get_clean();
    return $return_string;
}

    ob_start(); //workaround how to capture the output from comment_form() function
        comment_form("", $post_id);
    $capture_comment_form = ob_get_clean();


    $return_string = $return_string 
                . $capture_comment_form
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>';
```

I need to fix the `href` part of the reply link?

Comment: Your link is gone/not here.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that `comment-reply.js` is not loaded and it fixed the issue.

Could someone explain? I have no idea what happened.

So the fix was adding `wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );` to my plugin code.

Comment: If you show us when and where you add the reply script in your theme, then yes, we'd be able to explain :)

Comment: I updated the code in my questions. It is just after the code that I posted the first time....